# How to get an App id on bing to use API's? (website instructions not working)

Tags: bing, api

I'm just switching from the Google Maps API to Bing since Bing's tos allows commercial storage of geocoding results. I was able to sign up for a Microsoft live registration and get a Bing Maps API key. But I need an app id too. I tried these directions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440736.aspx

But when I go to the developer center, I see nowhere to login and nothing that refers to an app id. When I search on the developer center for an app id, all I get is the reference to the instructions above. I tried contacting Microsoft/Bing, but all their links for "technical support" are failing so I'm at a loss. Can anyone tell me another way to get an app id for purposes of using Bing mapping API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found their alternate help page:
http://www.bingmapsportal.com/

> Your Bing Maps Account lets you create Bing Maps Keys to use with the Bing Maps APIs. You can also create and manage data sources that contain entities with a location.

What a boondoggle to get there!

Comment: Ok but ... inside the private area of that site, where do you find the app id ? It's still unclear